# state update on an unmounted component. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native

i'm trying to use ListEmptyComponent in FlatList

if i don't have data i want to show ListEmptyComponent={}

However, in the Loadingsecoend component, I use useEffect to render  when loading is true, and no data after 2 seconds, i.e. when loading is false Try to render.. but if i use this code this error occure

```
 state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a 
 memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and 
 asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function.
```

i understood what is the reason . but i have no idea how can i fix...

this is my code

(todoList.js)

```
            return (
                <FlatList
                data={getComment}
                keyExtractor={(item) => String(item.id)}
                initialNumToRender={50}
                ListEmptyComponent={<Loadingsecoend />}
                renderItem={({item}) => (
                    <TodoItem
                    item={item}
                    
                    />
                )}

                />
            );
```

(Loadingsecond.js)

```
            const Loadingsecoend = () => {

            const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

            useEffect(() => {
                setLoading(true);
                setTimeout(() => {
                setLoading(false);
                },2000);
            },[]);

            
            return (
            
            loading ? (
                <Container>
                <ActivityIndicator color="#D3D3D3" size="large" />
                </Container>
            )
                :(<Container>
                <Label>no data</Label>
                </Container>)
            
            );
            };
```

how can i resolve this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should clear the timer in a cleanup function. The component is unmounting for some reason *before* the timeout expires and so you are attempting to set state of an unmounted component. Returning a cleanup function from an `useEffect` hook is called to *clean up* any effects from the current render cycle. When used with an `useEffect` hook with empty dependency it is synonymous to `componentWillUnmount`, in other words, it runs before the component unmounts.

```
useEffect(() => {
  setLoading(true);
  const timerId = setTimeout(() => {
    setLoading(false);
  }, 2000);

  return () => clearTimeout(timerId);
}, []);
```